# Создание графических обьектов на основании введенных чисел, координат C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Всем привет, нужна помощь...Нужно написать программу которая на основании введенных чисел координат, рисовала, а так же брала готовые графические объекты и создавала бы что то наподобие карты. Допустим вы забили данные в виде чисел, а программа вывела бы графическую карту на основании этих чисел. Куда копать? Paint WPF без кистей через окна ввода данных? Может какие исходники есть?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делайте контролы для объектов, размещайте их на Canvas, например. Пока вопрос слишком общий

Answer (score 0):

Нашел достойный пример, но сейчас дорабатываю и есть вопросы, отдельно создам новый вопрос, вот ссылка на проект: https://github.com/talasbaev/LabApp.git

Answer (score -1):

Допустим вы используете WPF.

Создаете контрол который будет холстом (допустим grid с именем grd)
На него динамически (тоесть в коде) добавляете елементы.
Пример с кнопкой:

```
Button b = new Button()
b.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
b.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
b.Margin.Top = [твоя позиция по y];
b.Margin.Left = [твоя позиция по x];
b.Width = [ширина];
b.Height = [высота];
grd.Children.Add(b)
```

Comment: Для создания овала используй Ellipse вместо Button

Comment: Для стрелок https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476257/drawing-arrow-with-xaml (второй ответ)

Comment: Для контуров ипользуй Path. У него нужно будет редактировать позиции точек по которым проходит кривая, но я думаю это не сложно найти в инете